# How to make available "open this project in IntelliJ IDEA" option in Windows context menu, if IntelliJ IDEA has been installed via JetBrains Toolbox?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-toolbox

If to install some of IntelliJ IDEA family IDE manually, it will be suggested "add 'open this directory in IntellIJ IDEA' in context menu" in installation master. However, if to install IDE via JetBrains Toolbox there will not be available this option.

Comment: If you use Ubuntu (like me). Use [this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#toolbox) to be able to open Intellij on Terminal. Then use [this app - FileManager-Actions](https://github.com/GNOME/filemanager-actions) to be able to open any command on context menu, and *"any command"* here is the `idea` command.

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh, thank you for the comment. Not using yet, but I'm considering the migration to Linux in the future.

Answer (score 4):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-2478 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Other tickets with similar requests (that *I think* should be marked as Duplicate to the aforementioned one or some other way around): [TBX-3573](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-3573), [TBX-3981](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-3981)